# Idle RPM is not setting properly sometimes

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor, idle, rpm

I have an Apache RTR 180 (Carbureted)

Sometimes, when I downshift, and when shifting down to 1st gear (to stand still), the RPM shows somewhere around 2000. The normal idle is around 1200 - 1400 RPM.

I must release the clutch a little bit to slow the engine back to 1200 - 1400.

This happens regardless of the temperature and even if I have only driven a few kilometers..

What would be the cause for a high idle?  What can I check and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: What happens if you push the throttle closed manually, rather than relying on the return spring?

Comment: @SimonMoss: Hi, I am closing the throttle manually and not relying the return spring...

Comment: When you first start the bike is the idle speed normal?  What happens if you rev the engine without going anywhere?  There must be some threshold.

Comment: Hi @JPhi1618: When starting the bike, it behaves perfectly at the idle RPM.  
>>What happens if you rev the engine without going anywhere? - That is also doing fine. It comes backs to the Idle RPM...
Thanks...

Comment: If you don't use the clutch to bring the engine speed down, what happens? Does it eventually drop?

Comment: Hi @SimonMoss: It is there atleast for some minutes. I have not checked for the minutes calculation. But it stays there..

Comment: Dirty carbs can mess with your idle a lot. When was the last time they were taken apart and cleaned?

Answer (score 0):

Its the air fuel ratio problem bro. Air fuel ratio is not proper in your bike. I too facing this problem in my rtr 180. Retune your carburetor.
1. Warm your bike to optimal temperature 
2. Turn the fuel screw clockwise to lean the mixture to lowest as possible(at this stage humming of engine is very unstable)
3. After getting the leanest possible point, turn the fuel screw to anticlockwise to 3 full turns and leave it thats the optimum/balanced setting for apache 180 recommended by company.